Is there any necessary action regarding nodes of a content type in case I want to change the language of that content type?
I have a content type of language A and I further have one node of that content type, which is in language A as well (no translations).
I plan to change the language of the content type from language A to language B but I don't know if I should programmatically change the language of the one node it has from A to B before I change the language of the entire content type.
Is there any necessary action regarding nodes of a content type in case I want to change the language of that content type?

On the content type you're only setting the default language for newly created nodes of that type. So that shouldn't effect an existing nodes
On newly created nodes the "original language" will be whatever the default language was when the node was created. So if you change the default to LanguageB then new nodes will show the original as LanguageB. For the existing nodes it will still show the original language as LanguageA even after you change the default language to LanguageB.
